# ImageView as a child of ViewPager2 is resizing on software keyboard display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, imageview

So I have an app that has a fragment inside of it that contains an `ImageView`; I was looking to redesign some navigation from using a drawer to a `TabLayout`, and it all goes off flawlessly except for one issue: if I just display the fragment with the `ImageView` manually myself on an activity, the layout of the image correctly maintains its size in spite of the software keyboard being shown. However, when I let `ViewPager2` handle displaying the fragment in concert with `TabLayout`, the `ImageView` resizes to fit to the available screen height that is left when accounting for the software keyboard.

Here's a basic reproduction of my layouts:

- The layout containing the `ImageView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/input_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/input_image_desc"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/input_image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- The layout hosting the `ViewPager2`, which eventually gets the layout containing `ImageView` from a `FragmentStateAdapter.createFragment` instance:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- the layout for the activity (which is hosting all the fragments inside of the `FrameLayout`):

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried doing something like this but it didn't work properly:

```
(viewPager as ViewPager2).registerOnPageChangeCallback(object: OnPageChangeCallback(){
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            if (position != 0) return
            val selectedView = viewPager.get(position)
            selectedView.post {
                val wMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
                val hMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
                view.measure(wMeasureSpec, hMeasureSpec)
                viewPager.layoutParams.height = view.measuredHeight
            }
        }
    })
```

I've also seen some people mention changing a property in the android manifest to change how the hosting activity handles soft keyboard input, but this seems crazy to me because it will/could impact the behaviour of every fragment inside that activity, so I haven't even tried it.